# How can I reference a sheet that is named by the first part of the macro?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a macro that let's the user create a new sheet, name it, and then based on what option they've chosen, will paste a certain text in that new sheet. But my searching and piecing together only got me so far.

```
Sub AddNameNewSheet1()
Dim Newname As String
Newname = InputBox("Name for new account?")
If Newname <> "" Then
    Sheets.Add Type:=xlWorksheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = Newname
    Range("D1") = Newname
End If

Dim LR As Long, i As Long
With Sheets("Start Page")
    LR = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To LR
        With .Range("A" & i)
            If .Value = "Debit" Then
                Sheets("Account Styles").Range("A1:G3").Copy Destination:=Sheets("").Range("A1:G3")
            ElseIf .Value = "Credit" Then
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A1").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A2")
            ElseIf .Value = "Savings" Then
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A1").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A2")
            End If
        End With
    Next i
End With
```

A starting point would be great, as a lot of answers I find that are relatively similar are not similar enough for me to relate it to my project. I know that code might not be fixable in its current form. So far it works until "Sheets("Account Styles").Range("A1:G3")..."

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are **probably** wanting to know how to write `Sheets(Newname)`, but I could be completely misunderstanding your question.  It's not clear what is meant to be happening with each of your sheets.

Comment: It's probably easier to just ignore the code I have... I'm trying to create a macro that will ask for a name then create a new sheet with that name, then paste data on the new sheet based on what was chosen on the start page.

Comment: Then you are **definitely** wanting to know how to write `Sheets(Newname)`.  And you write it as ... `Sheets(Newname)`.  (You have the bit to create the sheet, and give it the name, so just refer to it using that name afterward.)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, there is still a lot of work in your project. In the code below I have streamlined your existing code a little so that you can see your next step more clearly. I hope it helps.

```
Sub AddNameNewSheet1()
    ' 21 May 2017

    Dim WsStart As Worksheet
    Dim WsNew As Worksheet
    Dim AccName As String
    Dim Rl As Long                                  ' last row
    Dim R As Long                                   ' row counter

    AccName = InputBox("Name for new account?")
    If AccName = "" Then Exit Sub

    Set WsNew = Worksheets.Add
    With WsNew
        .Name = AccName
        .Cells(1, "D").Value = AccName
    End With

    Set WsStart = Worksheets("Start Page")
    With WsStart
        Rl = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For R = 1 To Rl
            Select Case .Cells(R, "A").value
                Case "Debit"
                    .Range("A1:G3").Value = Sheets("Account Styles").Range("A1:G3").Value
                Case "Credit", "Savings"
                    .Range("A2").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
            End Select
        Next R
    End With
End Sub
```